# Getting ViewModel Data in my MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am sure this is relatively simple, I just keep running into brick walls. I have two entity classes set up like so:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

And I set up my ViewModel like this:

```
public class PostCommentViewModel
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Comment> Comment { get; set; }

    public PostCommentViewModel(int postId)
    {
        var db = new BlogContext();

        Post = db.Posts.First(x => x.Id == postId);
        Comment = db.Comments;
    }
}
```

And I have my Controller doing this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        var viewModel = new PostCommentViewModel(id);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

And then the view looks like this:

```
@model CodeFirstBlog.ViewModels.PostCommentViewModel


<fieldset>
<legend>PostCommentViewModel</legend>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Post.Title)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Post.Content)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Post.CreatedDate)
<hr />    
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comment)
</fieldset>
```

The result IS displaying data, but not quite what I want for the comments.

[image]

You see that the comments (There are two of them) and just showing the id property on each one "12"

How can I get it to go into and display the comment details specific to this particular post? I imagine a foreach loop is in order, but i cant figure out how to drill into the Model.Comment property correctly.

I tried this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Comment)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(item.DisplayName)
@Html.DisplayFor(item.Content)
@Html.DisplayFor(item.DateCreated)
}
```

But the error I get is "The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Not sure what I am supposed to do here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop around the comments model:

```
@model CodeFirstBlog.ViewModels.PostCommentViewModel


<fieldset>
<legend>PostCommentViewModel</legend>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Post.Title)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Post.Content)
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Post.CreatedDate)
<hr />    
@foreach(var comment in Model.Comment) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => comment)
}
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Don't you need comment.content ?

Comment: This works. If I want my content I just need to do (x => comment.Content)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [DisplayTemplate](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) for your `Comment` class and it should work, there is no need to iterate over the collection the view engine does it for you.

As per my comment, this is all you need to do to create a display template for your `Comment` class:

Create a `DisplayTemplates` subfolder inside your view folder and inside this create a new partial view called `Comment.cshtml`. Your template could look like this:

```
@model CodeFirstBlog.ViewModels.Comment

<div class="comment">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DisplayName)
    ....
</div>
```

And that's it! If you need more control over how your comment is displayed then you can simple tweak the template to suit.

Comment: Alright, at the risk of sounding dumb, I don't get it. I looked through the link, and it seems awesome, but I can't get it to render on my project. Can you elaborate or give an example?

Comment: @davidisawesome sure I will update my post. I see you have already accepted an answer, however, like I said there should be no need to iterate over the collection.

Comment: If I can get your solution to work than I will happily switch the accepted answer. Both would be correct, but credit would go to you for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for that sample, but now I am running into a data issue. It is giving me this error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[CodeFirstBlog.Models.Comment]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CodeFirstBlog.Models.Comment'."

Comment: Looking at your code, you probably don't want to be passing your actual entities to your views, you should create a `PostViewModel`/`CommentViewModel` and map your properties to them. As for the error, only thing I can think of is the template stuff doen't like `DbSet`, try changing it to a `List<Comment>` in the `PostCommentViewModel` and try that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PostCommentViewModel 
{ 
    public Post Post { get; set; } 
    public IQueryable<Comment> Comment { get; set; } 

    public PostCommentViewModel(int postId) 
    { 
        var db = new BlogContext(); 

        Post = db.Posts.First(x => x.Id == postId); 
        Comment = Post.Comments; 
    } 
}
```

And did you make Html helper method for Comment class?